# Few angular services, differing only in constants

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm pretty new to angularjs and I need to do the following:
I have few partial views, each containing simple configuration form, which needs to be fetched/PUT to server.

Each view has a controller, each controller has a corresponding service which is responsible for doing GET/PUT request to a given backend endpoint.

Services differs right now only in endpoint url.

The question is: 
**how would you avoid the following?**

```
var providerConfigService = function ($http) {


    this.fetchConfig = function (endpointUrl, success, failure) {
        $http.get(endpointUrl)
            .success(function (data) {
                success(data)
            })
            .error(function (data, status) {
                failure(status)
            });
    };


    this.updateConfig = function (endpointUrl, config, success, failure) {
        $http.put(endpointUrl, config)
            .success(function (data, status) {
                success()
            })
            .error(function (data, status) {
                failure(status)
            });

    }
};

var facebookConfigService = function (providerConfigService) {
    var facebookEndpoint = "";

    this.fetchConfig = function (success, failure) {
        providerConfigService.fetchConfig(facebookEndpoint, success, failure)
    };

    this.updateConfig = function (config, success, failure) {
        providerConfigService.fetchConfig(facebookEndpoint, config, success, failure)
    };

};

// POTENTIALLY DUPLICATED CODE FOR OTHER VIEWS
// SERVICE REGISTERING
```

I'm more like a Java guy, so I would do something like this in Java and Spring world:

Provide `endpointUrl` as a constructor parameter, then either create a Factory class or just declare preconfigured beans.

**I'm looking for a similar solution in angular world. Should I use angular's factories/providers? If so, how?** It's probably straightfroward, but I'm quite confused with angular's services/controllers/factories/providers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically in the angular world you would try and use [ng-resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource). If your API's are RESTful and basic I would recommend ng-resource.  If not, then it's ok what you've done, but typically those gets and puts would just be within the provide service itself.  You're only DRY-ing up the success and failure but the reality is that those would probably be different anyway.

Comment: Although it doesn't answer my question completely - ng-resource was the way to go in this particular case, thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Factory ([read more](http://tylermcginnis.com/angularjs-factory-vs-service-vs-provider/)) and configure it in your controller. You can also improve the flow by using promises instead of passing callbacks.

```
   angular.module('yourapp')
   .factory('configFactory', function ($http) {
     return {
       endpointURL: "", // this is what you modify
       fetchConfig: function () {
        $http.get(this.endpointURL)
       },

       updateConfig: function (config) {
         $http.put(this.endpointURL, config)
       }
     };
   })
   //and your controller
   .controller('someCtrl', function($scope, configFactory){
     configFactory.endpointURL = 'http://customurl.com';
     // configFactory will use the endpointURL defined by this controller
     $scope.fetchConfig = function(){ 
       configFactory.fetchConfig().then(function(){}).catch(function(){});
     }
   })
   // and another
   .controller('someCtrl', function(configFactory){
     configFactory.endpointURL = 'http://anotherurl.com
   })
```

Comment: I should mention that the key here is using a factory. A service/provider will be changed globally, but factories are like an instance of whatever is defined, so it's safe to change it in one controller without effecting another.

Comment: I wish I could accept both @Arthur Frankel's answer and yours.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I ended up with the following:

My ng-resources:

```
var ConfigurationResource = function ($resource, endpointUrl) {
    var allowedMethods = {
        'get': {
            method: 'GET'
        },
        'update': {
            method: 'PUT'
        }
    };

    return $resource(endpointUrl, {}, allowedMethods);
};

var FacebookProperties = function ($resource) {
    return ConfigurationResource($resource, 'my.facebook.endpoint.url');
};
```

And there was a problem with duplicating code in my controller, so it now looks like the following:

```
var PropertiesController = function (scope, propertiesResource) {
    this.fetchProperties = function () {
        propertiesResource.get(function (fetchedProperties) {
            scope.properties = fetchedProperties;
        });
    };

    this.updateProperties = function () {
        propertiesResource.update(scope.properties)
    };

    scope.properties = {};

    scope.fetchProperties = this.fetchProperties;
    scope.updateProperties = this.updateProperties;

    scope.fetchProperties();
};

var facebookConfigController = function ($scope, FacebookProperties) {
    new PropertiesController($scope, FacebookProperties);
};
```

Maybe that's not the proper way to do this, but at least it works and there's almost no boilerplate.